# How to build a splash screen for IOS and Android

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I am finalizing a App for Android and IOS with Cordova.
I use the cordova-plugin-splash, but I have a lot of issue with IOS, specially with the splash images.

I wonder if there is a standard to do splash csreen with Jquery Mobile only, as adding a white div with a image. The idea is to remove the splash plugin and use only jquery mobile.

My need is to have a splash screen for about 1-2 second, to hide the app loading process and must work on IOS and Android devises

All topics I red by stackoverflow are too old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I would use plain JavaScript instead of JqueryMobile.

```js
(function() {
  setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
          document.getElementById("splashScreen").style.display  = "none";
          document.getElementById("mainMenu").style.display = "inline";
      }, 2000)
})();
```

```html
<div id="splashScreen">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div id="mainMenu">
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Or use Jquery as an alternative.

```js
$(document).ready(
  setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
          $("#splashScreen").hide();
          $("#mainMenu").show();
      }, 2000)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="splashScreen">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div id="mainMenu" style="display: none;">
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```